# ContentEditable iframe is not editable in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, yui, contenteditable

I am having an issue with contentEditable iframes in Firefox. I created an iframe for pasting rich text and it worked excellently in Chrome. However, for some reason the iframe is not editable in Firefox and IE. When I load the iframe in FF, the cursor blinks in the iframe and then disappears, never to return. Here is the HTML as it loads in Chrome:

```
<iframe id="atto_pastespecial_iframe" frameborder="0" style="border: 1px solid gray">
#document
     <html>
         <head></head>
         <body contenteditable="true"></body>
     </html>
</iframe>
```

However, here is how it looks in FF:

```
<iframe id="atto_pastespecial_iframe" frameborder="0" style="border: 1px solid gray">
#document
     <html>
         <head></head>
         <body></body>
     </html>
</iframe>
```

I am adding the HTML via YUI Javascript: (Edit to show how the iframe is added)

```
_addIframe: function(container) { //Container points at div to insert iframe into
    container.setHTML('<iframe id="atto_pastespecial_iframe" src="javascript: window.onload(document.getElementByTagName(\'body\').contentEditable=\'true\')" frameBorder="0" style="border: 1px solid gray"></iframe>');
    var ifr = Y.one('#atto_pastespecial_iframe');
    var doc = ifr.get('contentWindow.document');

    // Set the iframe to be editable by the user
    doc.one('body').setAttribute('contentEditable', 'true');
    doc.one('body').focus();
```

Does anyone know why the iframe is editable in Chrome, but not FF or IE?

Comment: I am able to get the content to be editable in FF by opening up the Inspector and editing the <body> tag (r-click, select "Edit as HTML") and adding contenteditable="true". This add <br _moz_editor_bogus_node="TRUE"></br> in the <body> tag. How do I make this happen automatically?

Comment: I have been able to get success in FF by adding src="javascript:window.onload(document.getElementsByTagName('body').contentEditable='true';", but this causes IE to fill the iframe with "Page not found". Any ideas?

Comment: How are you creating the iframe?

Comment: I am loading it with javascript. I added the lines to show you how I insert the iframe as HTML.