# Dynamically created editable iframe not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe, createelement

I have an iframe that is generated in JavaScript with `createElement()` when a function is fired, which becomes a text editor. It works just fine in Chrome, Safari and Edge, but in Firefox, the `innerHTML` text, "Text Layer", will briefly flash within the iframe and then it disappears and the iframe doesn't seem to be editable. Upon inspection, the iframe's body tag is empty. If I set `contentEditable` to true on the iframe's body tag in the inspector it seems to work properly, but when I try to set this in my JS function, nothing happens in Firefox.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the iframe being created in JavaScript, since setting the `designMode` of an iframe already in the DOM to `'On'` with JS seems to work properly. Wondering if there's a way to get this to work in Firefox, maybe another method of creating the iframe? I have seen some similar problems that were solved by putting some javascript in the iframe's `src`, as in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422219/contenteditable-iframe-is-not-editable-in-firefox), but that apparently causes problems in other browsers. Creating the iframe in JS is preferable to appending it from somewhere.

```js
function text() {
var rtf = document.createElement("iframe");
rtf.name = "richTextField";
rtf.id = "richTextField";
rtf.className = "texteditor";
var dwrap = document.createElement("div");
dwrap.appendChild(rtf);
var tframe = document.getElementById("richTextField");
tframe.contentWindow.document.designMode = 'On';
tframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "Text Layer";
tframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].focus();
tframe.onload = autosize();
};
```

Comment: looks like either a bug or security feature .. Have you tried looking for similar issues in Mozilla bug-tracker ?

Comment: I've found what seems like the same issue when setting stuff on the `contentWindow`, albeit from 15 years ago: [link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=236547) Looks like maybe I should try setting `designMode` in an `onload` function. Will update post with results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found this [15 year old bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=236547) and was able to get it work by setting the contentWindow properties inside of a setTimeout function.

```js
function text() {
var rtf = document.createElement("iframe");
rtf.name = "richTextField";
rtf.id = "richTextField";
rtf.className = "texteditor";
var dwrap = document.createElement("div");
dwrap.appendChild(rtf);
var tframe = document.getElementById("richTextField");

setTimeout(function(){ 
tframe.contentWindow.document.designMode = 'On';
tframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "Text Layer";
tframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].focus();
}, 0);

tframe.onload = autosize();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this had me going up the wall, everything is being triggered after DOMContentLoaded for me but it would still fail to insert the content, I realised putting an alert box just before setting innerHTML was just enough of a delay to work properly, although a pop up box isn't ideal. I guess this timeout trick is effectively given the same script break required as alert() for it to work. Pretty crazy but thanks!